# ionic upload gives Forbidden upload (403) error

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Hi i'm using ionic 2 and I uploaded my app earlier on succesfully.
But today I get the following error using 'ionic upload' command:

```
Uploading app....
An error occurred uploading the build: Forbidden upload (403)

Forbidden upload (403) (CLI v2.1.17)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.4
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.17
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.47
ios-deploy version: 1.8.2
ios-sim version: 3.1.1
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.9.2
```

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somehow I was logged out of my ionic account.
By logging in again, using the `ionic login` command and then using `ionic upload` again, my problem was solved.

By the way: after I was succesfully logged in I first got the error that the app id didn't excist. That was because of the fact that I deleted my app in the [ionic app portal](https://apps.ionic.io/).

You can create a new app by hand in the portal and then copy the app id into the `ionic.config.json` file in your app root folder.

Then run the `ionic upload` command again.

Comment: I wonder if they reset the login authentications? Maybe its on a timer?